# Disable onClick event on Osmdroid's overalys

Tags: android, overlay, osmdroid

how can I disable on click event on Osmdroid's Overlays which fire popup?

I've added into overlays json with route, and markers. On markers I disable it with this code:

```
Marker marker = new Marker(mapView);
marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But how could disable it on route? Here is code where I creating route:

```
FolderOverlay myOverLay = (FolderOverlay) kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(mapView, style, null, kmlDocument);
mapView.getOverlays().add(myOverLay);
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from the default KML styler in buildOverlay.

To avoid this bubble, you will have to implement your own [KML Styler](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_4#132-advanced-styling-with-the-styler).